# Materialize, mobile menu within static nav is behind modal?

Tags: html, css, materialize

If I paste this in a new html file, it looks like you would expect:

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[image]

But if I surround it with `<div class="navbar-fixed">`, as instructed [here](http://materializecss.com/navbar.html#navbar-fixed), then the menu is gray.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a pull request for a fix to the docs [here](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/pull/4482).

Essentially, you move the `.side-nav` element *outside* of the `.fixed-nav` element.

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
    <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
    <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
    <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add this snippet to your CSS code:

```
.nav-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```